# Notepad++ how to close this window?

Tags: notepad++

I have been trying to close this window that is drawn on top of notepad++ with no success. I closed notepad++ through task manager, then I opened it again and somehow I managed to hit the shortcut and open it again.

What is the shortcut to properly close this window ?

[image: 1]

Comment: You can usually bring that window up hitting `CTRL+TAB` and then it goes away after you select a file...can you not just select a file to have it go away, that is, after it comes up, does it not go away? I ask because I have had that happen where I couldn't get it to go away, though a restart of NP++ fixed that.

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes, it doesn't go away. Also, for some reason `ctrl + tab` doesn't do anything in notepad++ or even google chrome. I think it is because I have a razer keyboard with software that has re-written the functionality of that keystroke.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree about the custom keyboard software, but I don't have an answer for the NP++ issue as I've never been able to reproduce it reliably to troubleshoot it; do you happen to know how you get this to come up for you since your `ctlr+tab` isn't working?

Comment: ctrl+shift+tab also pops this up.

Comment: You can disable this behaviour in Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Document Switcher > Uncheck "Enable". I never use it anyway ;)